# Canonical injection

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Can we say canonical injection is equal to the natural injection?

I actually can not find an exact definition for canonical.

For example if
$ F_M : M  \rightarrow M'$ and $F_X : X  \rightarrow X' $ is $ I_M: M  \rightarrow X$ natural injection or canonical injection or could be both?

M is subspace of X, M and X are in Banach space and M' and X' are duality of M and X.

Comment: What are $M, M', X, X', F_M, F_X, I_M$? What is the canonical injection? What is the natural injection? Without these details an answer is impossible.

Comment: @s.harp I guess the definition for canonical injection is exactly what OP is looking for.